# How do I addclass. Working on mouseover but not on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my star rater to keep the background position of the sprite I'm using when clicking one of the 5 table columns inside a container div. On mouseover I'm adding a style attribute to do it and that works, but when I click and add a class with the same exact css in it it doesn't effect the background position. I've added the class by default and it still doesn't work. I guess this is really more of a css question than anything else.

Here is the code I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/cbYCZ/3/

Any help is greatly appreciated. This has been a real noodle scratcher for me.

Comment: Could you upload your stars image to server which doesn't require authentication?

Comment: I changed the image to pull from another server. It should work now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this rule:

```
#rating 
{
   background: ...;
}
```

And then this rule:

```
.star3
{
   background: ...;
}
```

Both of those are being applied simultaneously to the same element, but because of [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/), the one with an id (`#rating`) is overriding the one with a class (`.star3`), and so adding a `.class3` has zero effect whatsoever on the rendered page.

Changing `.star3` to `#rating.star3` fixes the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/gLTSz/

Answer (score 1):

you just add the id to `td` not to the div

just see this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cbYCZ/4/)

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see exactly what is going on as your image resource (*removed image path*) requires authentication.

However, I can see that you are not really using the jQuery api as it was intended:

For removing classes, you should be using `.removeClass()`

For adding and removing styles there is `.css()`

For adding and removing values there is `.val()`

For mouseover/mouseout there is `.hover()`

I would start by changing those and see if the problem persists. Otherwise you will need to put the stars image somewhere public so that we can see your code in action

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. In the mean time I have fixed the image if you'd like to see it in action now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is a lot more terse than your jQuery. You may find it teaches you a lot of more advanced techniques in a practical way.

I have commented the code fairly extensively. Let me know if you have any questions.

Note that my solution was dependent on the key observation by @Abhi Beckert, so he should get the Accepted Answer honours.

The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GtPnr/4/

And here is the new HTML:

```
<div id="rating">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="1star" data-stars="1"></div></td>
            <td><div id="2star" data-stars="2"></div></td>
            <td><div id="3star" data-stars="3"></div></td>
            <td><div id="4star" data-stars="4"></div></td>
            <td><div id="5star" data-stars="5"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="stars" />
```

And my terser, but commented, Javascript:

```
// store re-used jQuery objects in variables to greatly improve performance.
// this avoids re-creating the same jQuery object every time it is used.
var $rating = $('#rating');
var $starsField = $('#stars');
// use the .hover() as a shortcut for 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' handlers.
$rating.find('td').hover(function() {
    // remove all star classes then dynamically construct class name to add
    // using the data method to retrieve the value stored in the "data-stars" attribute
    // I added.
    $rating.removeClass('star1 star2 star3 star4 star5').addClass('star' + $(this).find('div').first().data('stars'));
}, function() {
    // this is the mouse-out handler. Remove all star classes
    $rating.removeClass('star1 star2 star3 star4 star5');
    // if the current value in the hidden field is set, then assign the correct class
    // so the star's clicked value is respected.
    var curVal = $starsField.val() || 0;
    if (curVal > 0) {
        $rating.addClass('star' + curVal);
    }
}).click(function() {
    // when clicking a star, store the value in the hidden input
    $starsField.val($(this).find('div').first().data('stars'));
});
```